# How does the definition of electrical power follow from the chain rule?

Tags: power, calculus

Just a small question for clarification.

Here's what I know:

- current *I* is defined by \$I = \frac{dq}{dt}\$ where *q* is charge and *t* is time
- voltage *V* is defined by \$V = \frac{dw}{dq}\$ where *w* is energy
- the chain rule is \$f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)\$

But I don't see how the definition of power \$P = \frac{dw}{dt}\$  follows from this. How do you use the chain rule on to show that power is just the product of current and voltage?

Answer (score 3):

You got the chain rule wrong. It actually is \$f'(g(x))g'(x)\$. Write the work as \$W(q(t))\$ and derive it to obtain the power. Be aware that \$W\$ is written as function of \$q\$, so \$W'=\frac{dW}{dq}\$.

Comment: You're right I'll correct that.

Answer (score 2):

\$P = \frac{dw}{dt} \$ by definition

\$V.I = \frac{dw}{dq} . \frac{dq}{dt} = \frac{dw}{dt}\$ by cancelling dq.

Comment: That's engineer's reply :) But this "canceling" is not obvious.

Comment: @EugeneSh. fair comment

Comment: I think it can be proved, for a small increment in time delta_t, I will change by dq/dt * delta_t. VI will change by dw/dq * dq/dt * delta_t. Change in VI / (change in t) is dw/dt. Change in VI / delta_t = dw/dq * dq/dt = V*I

Comment: Of course it can. But I think it is exactly what OP is asking for :) Anyway, it's more like math question..

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Keep in mind that the \$\frac{dx}{dy}\$ notation is just shorthand for \$\lim_{\Delta y\to 0} \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta y}\$. It isn't really all *that* hard to work out.

Comment: @DaveTweed Of course it is not. But, for instance, you should make sure this limit exist at all... But again, as mentioned in the first comment, it is good enough for engineers just to cancel it out. Or descend to math with all of the complications. The question is which scope is in OPs mind.

Comment: The cancellation principle is taught in high school, at least it was when I went some years ago, and is one of the advantages of Leibniz's notation over Newton's. It's akin to dimensional analysis. It is hand waving, but then so was all of calculus until *Principia Mathematica.*

Comment: @EJP What is not taught in the high school, that this principle is valid for a very narrow subset of functions only.

Comment: Its best to think through the problem and work it out from basic principles rather than following taught methods.